# Sending and receiving files over TCP connection between server and client

Tags: c#, tcp, xamarin, server, client

First of all, I'm very new to this topic so I searched around the Internet and found some things about TCP and socket connections. I have an app on my smartphone which acts as server and a WinForms application which is the client. Now I tried this in my App:

```
s.SendFile(outputFile);
```

where outputfile is an audio file in mp3 format and s is a Socket.

On the client side I have a TCP connection:

```
 using (var stream = client.TcpClnt.GetStream())
                using (var output = File.Create(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Audio.mp3")))
                {
                    // read the file in chunks of 1KB
                    var buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }
```

At the end I only receive an audio file which is 23kb big and can't be opened. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

I alos tried this

```
 Socket socket = TcpClnt.Client;
```

and then

```
 while ((bytesRead = socket.Receive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None)) > 0)
```

the file has still 23kb (maybe this is ok. I don't know) but the file is always corrupt and can't be opened by the media player.

Comment: Tried output.Close() after the while loop but this does not help

Answer (score 0):

Use this one for audio files:

```
Stream output = new StreamWriter(outputfilename,true)
Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(file);
Mp3Frame frame;
while ((frame = reader.ReadNextFrame()) != null)
{
output.Write(frame.RawData, 0, frame.RawData.Length);
}
```

Comment: This is with NAudio right? I would better do this without third party libraries when it's possible

Comment: your code for write file is correct make sure you have "s.SendFile(outputFile);" this create or send right object.

Comment: Yes I have. Still the file can not be opened.